# jQuery: If number above 3 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

How can I see if a SPAN contains a number over 3 digits? I tried the below, but it didn't work.

```
    if ($('.pointScore .score').val() > 999 ) {    
        alert("Over 999 point");    
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most likely .val() returns it as a string. try `.val() > "999"`

Comment: Don't you need a cast to Integer? I'm guessing the span value is string. PerfectlyNormal's suggestion is dangerous BTW. You shouldn't compare strings with greater or less.

Comment: @PerfectlyNormal, @Vladislav: No, JavaScript does that kind of thing for you. Even gets it right, much of the time. Best to use `parseInt`, but *possible* not to.

Comment: @T.J. That's why I changed "can't compare" to "shouldn't compare" before I posted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH!

I just needed to change val() to text()...

Sorry...

```
    if ($('.pointScore .score').text() > 999 ) {    
        alert("Over 999 point");    
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You noticed that a `span` doesn't have a value, but there is another potential problem with the code. The text is a string, so you will be comparing a string to a number. As that can have unexpected results, it should be avoided.

The easiest way is to simply check the length of the string:

```
if ($('.pointScore .score').text().length > 3) {    
    alert("Over 999 point");
}
```

You can also parse the string into a number:

```
if (parseInt($('.pointScore .score').text(), 10) > 999) {    
    alert("Over 999 point");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a case where the text comparison fails but I can't, are you sure it's not cast automatically?

Comment: Even better, include the radix in the `parseInt` so that everyone treats `0999` the same rather than it varying by implementation... Edit: Ah, okay, so with `parseInt` I'm not immediately seeing it vary by implementation (unlike number literals), pretty universally coming back `0`. Still, though, with the radix param (using `10`) it comes back `999` which is probably more useful.

Comment: @Andrew: It seems like Javascript is pretty good at guessing what you mean when mixing types, but you should still make sure that conversion is done the way you want and not rely on the Javascript engine to try to figure out what you intended.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yes, the `parseInt` should of course have the radix. I corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you could use the length property

```
if ($('.pointScore .score').html().length > 3) {    
        alert("more than 3 digits");    
    }
```

Comment: `<span class='score'>1<span>23</span></span>`